# Laravel - Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to grab a model and update one of the fields but i keep receiving this error message.

`Creating default object from empty value`

```
 if(isset($data['code']) && $data['code']){
            $invite = \App\Invite::where('code', $data['code'])->first();
            $invite->accepted = 1;
            $invite->save();
        }
```

I have never seen this error before am i grabbing the model incorrectly when updating the `accepted` field?

Comment: `dd($invite);` to see if you actually get something back

Comment: `$invite` is null,  so you getting this error. As lagbox said already as answer. I suggest you to use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()`, then it will throw a 404 error instead of this error.

Answer (score 2):

`first()` can return `null`. So your query did not return a result so `$invite` is `null`. If you try to assign a property to `null` you get that error, as it creates a default object and sets that property on it.